# Implementation of tree with classes in c++

Tags: c++, tree

Im trying to implement a tree that stores the vector of children at a given node. I've implemented the `find_index` function that finds nodes. It has two arguments: `Node * cur` and some `key`. I'm trying to use this function while working on `insert`, but I don't know what `Node*` to search for. Such a node must exist, but I don't know which one to call `find_index` with. Also I don't know if my functions are working properly. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Node{
    public:
    Node *parent;
    vector < Node* > children;
    string key;
    Node(){
        parent=NULL;
    }
};
class tree{
    public:
    int size;
        tree(){
            size=0;
        }
    Node* find_index(Node *cur,string key){
        Node *tmp;
        if(cur->key==key){
            tmp=cur;    
        }
        if(cur==NULL){
            tmp=NULL;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<cur->children.size();i++){
            find_index(cur->children[i],key);
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    void  add(){ 
        string father,son;
        while(cin>>father>>son){
            if(find_index(?,father)==NULL){//I don't know what node to put instead of question mark and is my function working
                size++;
                Node *newnode=new Node();
                newnode->key=father;
                newnode->parent=NULL;
            }
            else if(find_index(t,son)==NULL){
                size++;
                Node *newnode1=new Node();
                newnode1->key=son;
                newnode1->parent->children.push_back(newnode1);
            }
            else{
                Node *newnode2=new Node();
                newnode2->key=father;
                Node *newnode3=new Node();
                newnode3->key=son;
                newnode2->children.push_back(newnode3);
                newnode3->parent=newnode2;  
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt your code is working. I can see the following problems:

- `find_index`: If cur is NULL, you segfault on `cur->key` (in the first `if`)
- `find_index`: You never evaluate the results in the foor loop
- `add`: You need to store the tree's root for your `?` part.

As I don't know, how your input actually looks like. We could store a single root, if we knew the input would describe a tree top down. I'm gonna store multiple roots during `add` though. That way, you can build your tree bottom up as well.

A possible solution could be [something like this](http://ideone.com/qkpgB7).